# Proof verification of Lemma $2.3.3$ from Analysis I by Terence Tao.

Tags: solution-verification, induction, natural-numbers

At this point we can use everything we know about addition and order. (I will still mention everything I use from the previous sections).

Multiplication is defined as such:

> **Definition $2.3.1.$** *(Multiplication of natural numbers)*. Let $m$ be a natural number.
> To multiply zero to $m$, we define $0 \times m := 0$. Now suppose inductively that we
> have defined how to multiply $n$ to $m$. Then we can multiply $n++$ to $m$ by defining
> $(n++) \times m := (n \times m) + m$.

Where $n++$ is the successor of $n$.

We also proved that multiplication is commutative i.e. $n\times m=m \times n$ for all $n$,$m$ natural numbers.

I also call upon his second Peano axiom and a collorary

> Axiom $2.3$. $0$ is not the successor of any natural number; i.e., we have $n++ = 0$ for every natural number $n$.

> Corollary $2.2.9$. If $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers such that $a + b = 0$, then $a = 0$
> and $b = 0$.

---

**Lemma $2.3.3$** *(Positive natural numbers have no zero divisors).* Let $n$, $m$ be natural
numbers. Then $n\times m=0$ if and only if at least one of $n$, $m$ is equal to zero. In
particular, if $n$ and $m$ are both positive, then $nm$ is also positive.

Proof ($1$st try). We fix $m$ and induct on $n$. For $n=0$ we have to prove that $\forall m(0\times m=0\iff m=0)$ which is true by definition of multiplication. Now suppose the statement is true for $n$ i.e., $\forall n$,$m(n\times m =0 \iff [(n=0)\lor (m=0)])$. Since by Axiom $2.3$ we have $n++\neq 0$ the statement for $n++$ that we need to prove is $\forall n$,$m[(n++)\times m=0\iff m=0]$ which by the definition of multipliaction is equivalent to $\forall n$,$m[(n\times m)+m=0\iff m=0]$. First we show $(\implies)$ i.e., $\forall n$,$m[(n\times m)+m=0\implies m=0]$. Assume that $\forall n$,$m[(n\times m)+m=0]$ and suppose that $m\neq 0$ then by definition, $m$ is positive. Thus $(n\times m) +m=0$ yields a contradiction by Corollary $2.2.9$ so $m=0$. Now we prove $(\impliedby)$ i.e., $\forall n$,$m[m=0 \implies (n\times m)+m=0]$. Suppose that $m=0$ then $(n\times m)+m=(n\times 0)+0=(0\times n)=0$ by definition. This closes the induction. $\square$

I'm not very comfortable with logic symbols so let me know if something shouldn't be written as it is.

I'm unsure on this proof since Tao gave a hint to prove the second statement first and I didn't do that and after completing my proof I still don't see why he gave that hint. Which suggests that maybe I've missed something here.

The hint was: " prove the second statement first". The second statement being "In particular, if $n$ and $m$ are both positive, then $nm$ is also positive."

After a few comments I've realized how that previous proof was nonsense so here I will try to incorporate Tao's hint.

Proof ($2$nd try). We first prove the second statement. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $nm=0$ and that $n$ and $m$ are both positive numbers. Since they are positive by Lemma $2.2.10$, $\exists !a$,$b$: $n=a++$ and $m=b++$. So $nm=0 \implies (a++)\times (b++)=0$. Which by definition can be written as $(a\times b++)+b++=0$ which by Corollary $2.2.9$ is a contradiction by Axiom $2.3$.

Now to prove the second statement; for $(\implies)$ if $n=0$ the statement is true by definition and commutativity of multiplication. For $(\impliedby)$ we take the contrapositive.

Comment: You should include that Hint in the Post. It might be that you used **"Something-Equivalent-to-it"** without knowing !

Comment: @Prem The hint was: " prove the second statement first". The second statement being "In particular, if $n$ and $m$ are both positive, then $nm$ is also positive." and I didn't even prove this here since proving the first almost directly implies the second by definition so I didn't even see it as something else that needed to be proved.

Comment: One quick comment: you say "we fix $m$" and then go into an argument starting with "for all $m$..." Likewise, you fix $n$ in the acceptance of the induction hypothesis and then use a universal quantifier to assume that your hypothesis is true for all $n$. This isn't true, as if it were, then it would be true for both some $m$ and $m+1$, and we'd be done. In these arguments, it's better to say "let $m$ be an arbitrary natural number" and then proceed as if it were a constant. I will look over the rest of the proof later today if time allows.

Comment: I've made this mistake before and while I've thought about how what I'm writing doesn't make sense, I couldn't formulate a way to say it. Would removing the quantifiers be a way to go here?

Comment: [[A]] Tao wants something like this : (2) When $m$ & $n$ are Positive , $mn$ is Positive. Hence , [ $mn=0$ ] & [ $m$ & $n$ are Positive ] will give Contradiction. (1) Prove [ $+ \times + = +$ ]. [[B]] Your Proof starts off wrong : $ 0 \cdot m = 0 \leftrightarrow m = 0 $ : Check $ 0 \cdot 8 = 0 \leftrightarrow 8 = 0 $ ?!?! Correction is essential here !

Comment: Oh yeah this was very wrong. Is there even a way to prove it directly like that then? Since $\forall n,n++\neq 0$ how could I formulate this statement? It seems impossible the way I set things up but as previously mentioned, proof by induction doesn't comply with the quantifiers of the statement.

Comment: Comments on proof 2: specify that $m$ and $n$ are positive natural numbers rather than numbers. I would recommend adding a comma after "Since they are positive." As written, it seems that they are positive because of Lemma 2.2.10, when in reality, they are positive by assumption. Specify that $a$ and $b$ are both natural numbers, and I personally do not know what you mean by $\exists !$. Your argument is missing an important detail: by corollary 2.2.9, both $a \times b^+$ and $b^+$ are 0. In particular, the latter is a contradiction of Axiom 2.3 (not axiom 2.2).

Comment: Two more comments on part 2 of proof 2: you can't assume that $n=0$. You have to assume that either $n=0$ or $m=0$ (or both). Also, you cannot prove that $A \iff B$ by proving that $A$ implies $B$ and then noting that the contrapositive is true. Indeed, the contrapositive of a true statement is always true. So all you've shown is that $A$ implies $B$ twice. You need to assume $B$ (i.e. $n \times m = 0$) and then showing $A$ (i.e. $n=0$ or $m=0$ (or both).

Comment: Nice attempts + great efforts shown here , +1 , keep up the overall learning Process + Progress !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[ Collecting my Comments + newer thoughts into this Answer ]]

**(A) There may be various ways to Prove that , Tao is giving the "Hint" to Prove it in a Particular way.**
(1) Prove that the Product of 2 Positive Integers is Positive Integer [[ $+ \cdot + = +$ ]] which should not be hard.
(2) Show that Product of 2 Positive Integers giving 0 is the **Contraction** to that.

**(B) OP-Proof-1 is starting off with a flaw :**
$\forall m(0\times m=0\iff m=0)$
This is wrong , because $ 0 \cdot 8 = 0 \iff 8 = 0 $ is wrong.
That makes the whole Induction **invalid** , in general.
I am not sure whether fixing that will help , here.

**(C) OP-Proof-2 looks better & more to the Point.**
**(C1)** It looks a little too long , it could be shortened.
**(C2)** User "Dr. Momo" has given Issues with this Proof. That should be rectified.

**(D) My Suggestion , I am giving it in elaborate Detail :**
**(D2)** Start with Product of 2 Positive Integers giving Positive Integer.
**Proof :** When we have $m$ & $n$ Positive , then we have $(m_1++) = m$ & $(n_1++) = n$ , hence we have $m \cdot n = (m_1++) \cdot (n_1++)$
$(m_1++) \cdot (n_1++) = m_1 \cdot (n_1++) + (n_1++)$
Here , $m_1 \cdot (n_1++) + (n_1++)$ cannot be 0 , because that will make Both terms 0 : In Particular , it will make $(n_1++) = 0$ , which can not occur , because O is not the Successor , according to Axiom.
In other words , Product of 2 Positive Integers is Positive Integer.
**(D1)** That immediately says that when Product of 2 Integers is 0 , at least 1 Integer must be 0.
**Proof :** When Both are not 0 (Positive) , Product is not 0 (Positive) , which we already Proved.

**(E) That way was the way Tao wanted the Proof ; Alternative ways may Exist.**
Particularly , **Induction ways** may Exist , though that was not necessary in my way.

Comment: Proof 2 is not correct. Please see my two comments in reply to the original post.

Comment: Thank you for Pointing out that **OP-Proof-2 is not right** , @Dr.Momo , I have mentioned that Point there , My Proof is not invalidated !

Comment: I’d like to point out that the last proof wasn’t meant to be a full proof and rather a collection of some ideas I had but still as @Dr.Momo pointed out even in that sketch a few mistakes were made (though I did mean to write Axiom $2.3$), if I find the time I’ll try and turn it into a proof though it would probably look a lot like yours.  I’m still interested in how an induction proof would go by proving the first statement to see exactly where I went wrong.

Comment: @ericforman No problem! Keep going. This is where real learning takes palce. I think it's doable with the strong principle of induction. I'll work on a proof after work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for an inductive proof of the forward implication of the first statement?

The goal is to prove that for all natural numbers $n$ and $m$,

$$(n \times m =0) \implies (n=0 \text{ or } m=0)$$

We fix $m$ and induct on $n$. For $n=0$ (the base case), we ask: is the following statement is true?

$$(0 \times m =0) \implies (0=0 \text{ or } m=0)$$

$0 \times m=0$ is a true statement (by the definition of multiplication), and since $0=0$ is true, the entire right side is true (definition of the or operator in logic). Thus the implication has the form $\text{True } \implies \text{True}$, which is a true statement.

Now, assume that the induction hypothesis is true and ask: is the following statement true?

$$(n^+  \times m =0) \implies (n^+ =0 \text{ or } m=0)$$

To prove a forward implication, you assume the left-hand side and prove the right-hand side. Indeed, let's assume that $n^+ \times m=0$. Note that we will never be able to prove that $n^+=0$, as this contradicts Axiom 2.3. So our only hope is to prove that $m=0$. We can now see that

$$n^+\times m=(n+1)\times m=n\times m+m=0$$

By Corollary 2.2.9, $n\times m=0$, but more notably, $m=0$ as desired. This closes the induction.

Note that we didn't actually use the induction hypothesis in this proof, which often means that induction was unnecessary.

Side note: please keep the thread going. I want to see if my own proof is correct. Like you, I am working my way through Analysis I right now, so I am as much of a student as you are.

Comment: Sure thing. I think I got a bit overzealous to finish this section on multiplication since the last one took some time and this seemed like a sort of repetition (which it kind of is, but still has some tricky parts). Because that set theory chapter looks quite daunting and I'm prepearing for uni so I'd like to go a bit faster. I also used logic symbols a bit too much and that funnily enough resulted in me thinking less logically about the problem at hand which resulted in that first proof. Now that I've distanced myself from it a bit and wrote things out explicitly the proof came out better.